# Specific .NET Regex Help

Tags: .net, regex

I need a .NET Regex that extracts the "field" and "width" values in the following string:

```
<element
    attribute='{field}'
    attribute='{field,}'
    attribute='{ field }'
    attribute='{ field, 0 }'
    attribute='{field,0}'
    attribute='{ field, 10 }'
    attribute='{field,10}'
    attribute='{ field, 100 }'
    attribute='{field,100}'
/>
```

I need to capture everything between the { and } characters then extract the field and width. Width is everything between the , and } characters. If no , character then width is Null/Nothing.

Comment: Why not, in this case, use Linq to XML?

Comment: I am not aware of how I can use Linq to Xml. I need to perform a method call on each match. Would this make a difference? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"\{\s*(?<field>\w+)\s*(,\s*(?<width>\d*)\s*)?\}"
```

**Usage:** Use `Regex.Matches` and extract the groups from each

**Edit:** You could add the static text in the expression too, but that would make it 'harder' to read IMO.